# Detecting is Div Out Of Screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I coded dropdown menu via javascript(w/ jQuery) and CSS. Dropdown menu works fine but if dropdown menu located at corner for example rightmost or leftmost of user screen then if user opens the dropdown menu, it overflows to unseen area of window and causes horizontal scroll-bar.

How can I stop overflowing ?

**HTML**

```
<ul class="dropdown">
    <li class="headlink">
        <a href="javascript://">Menu</a> <img src="/static/images/mini/sort_down.png" />

        <ul class="arrowlist invisible">
            <li>Hello 1</li>
            <li>Hello 2</li>
            <li>Hello 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.dropdown {z-index: 1}
.dropdown .headlink{border:1px solid #C7C9CF;padding:4px 6px;}
.dropdown li{}
.dropdown a{outline:none}
.dropdown ul{z-index:100;border:1px solid #C7C9CF;-moz-border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px;border-radius:4px;behavior: url(/static/css3pie.php);background: #FFF url("/static/images/grey_fade_back.png") repeat-x scroll bottom;padding:8px;position:absolute;top:-1px;left:-4px}
.dropdown ul li{margin:2px;white-space:nowrap}
```

**JS**

```
$('.dropdown li.headlink')
    .click(function() {
        $(this).css('position', 'relative');
        $('ul', this).slideDown(100);
    });

        $('.dropdown li.headlink')
    .mouseleave(function(){
        var headlink = this;
        $('ul', this).slideUp(100, function(){
            $(headlink).css('position', 'static');
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
$('.dropdown li.headlink')
    .click(function() {
        $(this).css('position', 'relative');

        if($('ul', this).width() + 10 > $(window).width() - $(this).offset().left) $('ul', this).css('left', 'auto').css('right', '-1px');
        else $('ul', this).css('left', '-4px').css('right', 'auto');

        $('ul', this).slideDown(80);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to store in a var the height in px of your drop down and check its y-offset. This post might be able to point you in the right direction [How to see if an element in offscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230414/how-to-see-if-an-element-in-offscreen) I wish I could provide you with working code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

replace:

```
.dropdown .headlink{border:1px solid #C7C9CF;padding:4px 6px}
```

with

```
.dropdown .headlink{border:1px solid #C7C9CF;padding:4px 6px;position:relative}
```

and replace

```
.dropdown ul {
  z-index:100;
  border:1px solid #C7C9CF;
  -moz-border-radius:4px;
  -webkit-border-radius:4px;
  border-radius:4px;
  behavior:url(/static/css3pie.php);
  background:#FFF url(/static/images/grey_fade_back.png) repeat-x scroll bottom;
  position:absolute;
  top:-1px;
  left:-4px;
  padding:8px;
}
```

with

```
.dropdown ul {
  z-index:100;
  border:1px solid #C7C9CF;
  -moz-border-radius:4px;
  -webkit-border-radius:4px;
  border-radius:4px;
  behavior:url(/static/css3pie.php);
  background:#FFF url(/static/images/grey_fade_back.png) repeat-x scroll bottom;
  position:absolute;
  left:-4px;
  padding:8px;
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The general solution to a problem like this is to, using either CSS or JavaScript, add a class to the first or last dropdown menu element so that it's alignment is corrected. In this specific case, with absolute positioning, changing the `left` and `right` property should do.

A simple example, for when the menu is right aligned and the right-most dropdown protrudes out of the screen, is to add a class with JavaScript which will shift the menu from the been aligned to the left side of the menu item to the right:

```
.dropdown ul {
    left: 0;
}

.dropdown ul.last {
    right: 0;
    left: auto;
}
```

**A simple demo of this can be found here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/yijiang/HyXuy/1/**

Comment: I've also made the liberty of correcting some of the problems in the code you presented originally.