# How do I dynamically change the css of an element that runs offscreen to make it stay onscreen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, position, positioning

I have what is for all intents a mouseover tooltip. It lives on multiple page elements (dynamically generated, so I never know how many there will be or what their positions are.)

I've had complaints that on lower-resolution screens, the tooltips on items in the rightmost column of elements run offscreen. Since I don't know the position of the parent item when it's created, I need a way to detect (before the mouseover actually happens) that the tooltip div will partially be offscreen when displayed, and change the css accordingly.

I know what the css needs to be; what I'm having trouble with is the detecting part. I've seen a [few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294284/how-to-know-when-an-element-will-be-off-screen) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230414/how-to-see-if-an-element-in-offscreen) that are similar, but the solutions all involve using prototype or jquery plugins. I'm limited to core jquery (or just plain javascript) on this project.

Any pointers out there?

Comment: every element has an offset from its parent, and every element would have a computedWidth (e.g. its size on the display). get those, figure out where the right-hand edge of the element is relative to the right-hand edge of the display, and shove it to the left if it goes offscreen.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. I've recently been messing around with [`position`](http://jqueryui.com/position/) in jQuery UI but no luck as of yet. If you take a look at the example on that link, you'll notice moving the orange div off the view pushes it's child DIVs to the right. Very similar to what you and I are looking for...

Comment: @FastTrack - I saw that sample in one of the questions I linked to, but it's using jqueryUI. As I said, I'm limited to core jquery - no UI, no plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick demo I put together on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2gGrd/

HTML:

```
<p class="left">Left</p>
<p class="center">Center</p>
<p class="right">Right</p>​
```

CSS:

```
p {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}

.left {
    left: 0;
}

.center {
    left: 50%;
}

.right {
    right: 0;
}

.toolTip {
    width: 100px;
    height: 25px;
    background: red;
    color: green;
    position: absolute;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var tip;

$('p').hover(function() {
    $(this).css('color', 'red');
    var xpos = $(this).width() / 2 + $(this).offset().left;
    var ypos = $(this).height() / 2 + $(this).offset().top;
    tip = createToolTip('thing', xpos, ypos);
    $(this).parent().append(tip);
    tip.offset({
        left: tip.offset().left - tip.width() / 2
    });
    if (tip.offset().left < 0) tip.offset({
        left: 0
    });
    if (tip.offset().left + tip.width() > $('body').width()) {
        tip.offset({
            left: $('body').width() - (tip.width())
        });
    }
}, function() {
    $(this).css('color', '');
    $(tip).remove();
});

function createToolTip(text, x, y) {
    return $('<div />').addClass('toolTip').css('left', x).css('top', y).text(text);
}​
```

It's not perfect code, nor is it the same idea as you have for the tool tips, but hopefully it answers the question about keeping the items on screen.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure that helps me. You're depending on the element's offset + width being greater than the body element's width to determine if an element is offscreen or not. Here's the thing: if the body element is set to 900px in CSS, the body width is always going to return 900px in javascript, even if the screen resolution is set so that only 600px are actually visible without scrolling. I need a way to determine if an element is visible on the screen, not if it technically is within the body element.

Comment: Usually if you want your page to have set width like that you would wrap all the page content in a page wrap div of some sort and give that the width and a margin auto if you want it centered horizontally on the page.